# Detect from which UILocalNotification an application was opened

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

In some cases my iOS application has to trigger **multiple `UILocalNotification`** at the **same time**. I want to decide which `UILocalNotification` the user clicked. When a user is clicking on a `UILocalNotification` the application was inactive or in the background. The problem is that the method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
```

is called for **each triggered `UILocalNotification`**. So when the app becomes active this method is called multiple times since I received multiple `UILocalNotification`'s. Is there a way to determine which `UILocalNotification` was the cause for the app to be opened? A check of applicationState is not working since all `UILocalNotification`'s have been received when the application was inactive or in the background.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
As an far example: When you receive a WhatsApp message from two different groups A and B and select push notification from group A this one will immediately displayed after the application opens itself. The difference between WhatsApp and my use case is that I have local notifications.

Comment: In my experience (and I just wrote a little test app that schedules three UILocalNotifications with the same fireDate when the app is closed to test this), when the user taps on a given alert in their notification screen, thereby launching the app, the only UILocalNotification that gets passed to UIApplication's didReceiveNotifications method is the one the user tapped on. So I'm not quite understanding your question.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but what about having just one local notification (i.e. cancelling previous ones). If you do so, you can keep track of the the notification's userInfo dictionary for later consumption when app becomes active. In case you still need multiple local notifications, would it be an option to group it somehow into a single one? If yes, you can prepare kind of array of userInfo dictionaries for its consumption when app becomes active.

Comment: Cant you use userinfo dictionary to figure out which notification was opened and check that in didRecieveLocalNotif,

Answer (score 9):

While sheduling the notification you can set the some unique id for notification userinfo.

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// set the your data with unique id
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict setObject:Id forKey:@"id"];

// assignt the dictionary to user info
    notif.userInfo=dict;


    notif.alertBody = @"test Notification";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

you can get the userinfo  from didReceiveLocalNotification like that

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"notification id %@",[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"id"]);
    }
    else if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"notification id %@",[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"id"]);
    }

    ////// or /////

    if ([notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"id"] )
    {
        NSLog(@"id of notification %@",[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"id"]);
    }

}
```

from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey])
    {
       UILocalNotification *notif=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        NSLog(@"notif.userInfo  %@",notif.userInfo);

//        notif.userInfo  {
//            id = 2;
//        }

    } 


        return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `launch options` to get access to the dictionary that was passed with the notification and from there, depending on what data you give the local notification when you're setting it up, you can check the dictionary and see which notification the method is responding to.

Comment: Hi pbush25, thank you for you response. Unfortunately, this won't help me to find out which UILocalNotification the user clicked since application:didReceiveLocalNotification is called for every UILocalNotification the user received simultaneously.

Comment: In addition launch options is only sent when the application is launched the first time not when coming active from background.

Answer (score 2):

Provide some unique information like id or something in the `UILocalNotification` userInfo property as `NSDictionary` when scheduling your notification. And when receive it either in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  or `didReceiveLocalNotification` take out the `user info` dictionary from notification instance and do your work accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use swift, I understand your app is probably running for iOS 8 and later.

If you use iOS8, you can provide actions to your notification (clicking on the notification is an action itself).

So you'll have this methods triggered through the `UIApplicationDelegate`:

[`application(_:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:)

And

[`application(_:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:withResponseInfo:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:withResponseInfo:completionHandler:)

Both this methods give you a `UILocalNotification` which [contains a `userInfo` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo) that you can fill when you create you notification and then put some kind of identifier for you to know which one is which.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addition to @pbush25, you can assign a dictionary object to property `notification.userInfo = [:]` just like that, then you can get it this way as well and use however you like!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.x use the following code in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // See if the application was launched from a local notification.
        if let options = launchOptions {
            if let notification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] as? UILocalNotification {
                print(notification.userInfo ?? "No info attached.")
            }
        }
        return true
}
```